# Convert test answer key in binary matrix with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I need some help about how to start develop a application in Android that recognize a test answer key and convert it to a binary matrix using OpenCV.

The test answer key filled will be like this:

[image: Card response]

And I wish to convert to a binary matrix to validate the responses, like this:

[image: Converted card response]

I don't want convert to another image, but to a int[10][5] variable matrix to use to iterate and validate the answers from response card in a Android app.

I tried tutorials that show how recognize circles, squares. But I didn't get nothing approximate to what I want and I have no idea how start with it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an image as above you basically know the coordinates of each circle. You could then take a sample from the centre of each of them and check if that is brighter or darker than 50% grey.

Comment: My idea is to use the Android's camera to read the image printed on paper. I'm trying to use openCV to recognize the circles and get the position of them, but never get recognized correctly and I don't know how restrict the area to read. I search for some tutorial, but I didn't find anything

Comment: The problem is that, how recognize the circles and positions... I have no idea how to do. I tried some tutorials that show how recognize spheres, circles, but with no success

Comment: I would try to match the whole chart. You've got the image of just the chart as above and you've got a photo of the chart in real life. I'd then try to do feature matching between those two using a feature matching algorithm like SIFT or ORB. Then you can compute a homography that can transform a coordinate from the original chart image into the photo.  Since you know the coordinate of each circle in the original, you can then transform this coordinate into the photo and take a sample at that position. Then you only have to decide from the sample if it's coloured or not.

Comment: Any progress? You can have a look at this feature matching class I wrote some time ago: [link](https://bitbucket.org/bastian_weber/hibo/src/e929579abd96b1a9470f1d6564f05513a9dd0fc2/KeypointMatcher.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [link](https://bitbucket.org/bastian_weber/hibo/src/e929579abd96b1a9470f1d6564f05513a9dd0fc2/KeypointMatcher.cpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)